# xsl:for-each loop, use xsl:if based on the index

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to write some logic based on the index inside xsl:for-each loop
for example.

```
<xsl:for-each select="address">
  <if index is 0>
      <EPAPARTMENT1> <xsl:value-of select="value" /> </EPAPARTMENT1>
  <if>
  <if index is 1>
      <EPDEPARTMENT2> <xsl:value-of select="value" /> </EPDEPARTMENT2>
  <if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please explain, how to get an index value inside xsl:for-each loop and how to use that with xsl:if

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are iterating over a node set you can use the `position()` function to return the current index within the node set. Note that this index is 1-based. So in your case you would write something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="address">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <EPAPARTMENT1> <xsl:value-of select="value" /> </EPAPARTMENT1>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
    <EPDEPARTMENT2> <xsl:value-of select="value" /> </EPDEPARTMENT2>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly I wanted to do.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Thanks for the correction! Which reminds me again never to write code without running it through the XSLT processor first...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `xsl:element` to programmatically create new elements if there are more than 2 element names you want to output.

### This XSL...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//address">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()" />
  <xsl:element name="EPAPARTMENT{$p}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

### When applied to this XML...

```
<xml>
 <address><value>AAA</value></address>
 <address><value>BBB</value></address>
 <address><value>CCC</value></address>
 <address><value>DDD</value></address>
</xml>
```

### Gives this output:

```
<EPAPARTMENT1>AAA</EPAPARTMENT1>
<EPAPARTMENT2>BBB</EPAPARTMENT2>
<EPAPARTMENT3>CCC</EPAPARTMENT3>
<EPAPARTMENT4>DDD</EPAPARTMENT4>
```